# Retriving data based on selected dropdownlist values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to display data based on the input given from two `DropDownList` in my view. What would be the best way to do this? How do I pass the `DropDownList` values to the controller?

Here is my controller

```
  // GET: Define
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Rooms = db.RM_ROOM.Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.NAME,
                Text = c.NAME

            });
            ViewBag.NAME = Rooms;

            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> item = db.RM_ENTITY_TYPE.Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.ENTITY_NAME,
                Text = c.ENTITY_NAME

            });
            ViewBag.ENTITY_NAME = item;
            //var rooms = db.RM_ROOM.ToList();

            return View();       
        }
```

Here is my Index

```
@using WebApplication1.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            Room
            @Html.DropDownList("NAME", "")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            Entity
            @Html.DropDownList("ENTITY_NAME", "")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my view model is

```
public class DefineViewModelcs
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Rooms { get; set; }

    public int ROOMID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Entities { get; set; }
    public int ENTITY_TYPEID { get; set; }
    public string ENTITY_NAME { get; set; }
    public int APPROVED_ROOM_STATEID { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: For your view you should be using `@using WebApplication1.DefineViewModelcs.cs` instead of `WebApplication1.Models` you want it to point to that specific view model, if it's in the Models folder then it would be `WebApplication1.DefineViewModelcs.cs`

Comment: I have used it at the beginning but did not copy it here

Answer (score 0):

First thing you will need to do is pass your value's from your view to your controller.

You could use an Eventlistener to detect changes in your dropdownmenu's to call your controlleraction by wrapping your dropdownmenu in a form.

```
    @using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName"))
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("IdOfDropDown",
                           "YourListToDisplayInsideTheMenu", 
                           new { onchange = “$(this.form).submit();”}
    }
```

Your controller will need to accept the input parameters.
Then you will need to use those value's to filter your search in your database

Last thing you need to do is return your search results to your view.

```
public ActionResult Filter(int id)
        {
          //Do your search here and return a list to the view, example:
          Room room = db.RM_ROOM.Find(r => r.ROOMID == id)

          return View(room);

          //this will return a single room from your database
        }
```

I'm not 100% sure of how your models work together and how they are defined, but i hope this helps you get on your way to finding the ideal solution to your problem.